# Compile Error; End With without With although both are there

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement

Currently working on a script to highlight a row if a specific cell within the row contains a certain phrase (the cell contains more than just the specific phrase). However, when trying to test, I am seeing the error "Compile Error: End With without With" I can see both the With and End With in my code, although it is possible I have been looking at this for too long to notice the obvious. Can anyone notice anything that could be causing this within the code?

```
Sub Conversion()

Dim State As String
Dim County As String
Dim Date As String
Dim TC As String    
Dim H As String
Dim Tmp As String
Dim m As Long
Dim x As Long    

H = "not recognised"
With Sheets("Matched Date")
 For Each cell In Sheet
    m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, H))
    If m > 0 Then
    Tmp = ""
    For x = 0 To m - 1
    Tmp = Tmp & Split(Rng.Value, H)(x)
    .Characters(Start:=Len(Tmp) + 1, Length:=y).EntireRow.Color = RGB(252, 227, 3)
    Tmp = Tmp & H
    Next
    End If
End With
```

Edit: Sorry about the amateurish code here, I'm not trained, just trying to do this based off simple online videos and google guides, as we have noone else to do this for us.

Comment: You're missing a `Next`. Use this cool [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) and you'll see it right away.

Comment: Learn to properly indent your code. It makes it much easier to trace the flow of execution and to identify this sort of issue.

Comment: `.Characters(Start:=Len(Tmp) + 1, Length:=y).EntireRow.Color = RGB(252, 227, 3)` looks (is) **very** problematic. A `Sheet` doesn't have a `Characters` property; `Characters` doesn't have an `EntireRow` property; and `EntireRow` (a `Range`) doesn't have a `Color` property.

Comment: Also, try to "label" the `next`s, so `for x=1 to 10:next x`

Comment: Re: your latest edit - no need to say sorry:) We are here to help. Hopefully we can give you good resources to improve your coding (e.g. the indenter link;  [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) is an amazing resource that you might consider). We all started from nothing at one point.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen that rubber duck tool is really useful! I’m hoping I can manage to get the rest of this done without messing too much up :P I’ve been trying to google most of my problems, and only ask when I genuinely can’t find an answer

Comment: That's all that's expected, an honest effort. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above already, proper code indention is your friend. Doing so, your code looks like

```
With Sheets("Matched Date")
    For Each cell In Sheet
        m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, H))
        If m > 0 Then
            Tmp = ""
            For x = 0 To m - 1
                Tmp = Tmp & Split(Rng.Value, H)(x)
                .Characters(Start:=Len(Tmp) + 1, Length:=y).EntireRow.Color = RGB(252, 227, 3)
                Tmp = Tmp & H
            Next
        End If
End With
```

That way, it's easy to spot that your 1st `For` loop is missing the closing `Next`.

This and similar error messages can be a bit misleading. It basically means "This code somehow misses a closing 'bracket'", if you think of the pairs `With/End With`, `For/Next`, `Select/End Select` etc. as opening/closing bracket pairs.

Comment: As mentioned in comments, `.Characters(Start:=Len(Tmp) + 1, Length:=y).EntireRow.Color = RGB(252, 227, 3)` has multiple issues, just a note. I anticipate another question shortly about it.